# How to fix date typos in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data set with a good hundred thousand lines in it.
somehow.. the data provider sent it to me with all the dates formatted like `1/1/20202021 08:07:43 AM` (mdy_hms). The correct year should be the last four in year for every row.

lubridate::mdy_hms() obviously cant recognize this. So I am trying to figure out how I could use grep or similar to pull out the correct date time. Any ideas?

Thanks everyone (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can handle this with functions in the `stringr` package. First, get the correct year by extracting it from the date variable. For example,

```
library(stringr)

date_value <- "1/1/20202021 08:07:43 AM"

correct_year <- str_sub(
  str_extract(date_value, pattern = "\\d{8}\\s"), 5, 10
)
```

This returns `"2021 "`. You can now use `str_replace()` to replace the 8-digit bad year with `correct_year`:

```
str_replace(date_value, pattern = "\\d{8}\\s", replacement = correct_year)

[1] "1/1/2021 08:07:43 AM"
```

To perform this operation across the whole data frame you can do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    date_value = str_replace(
      date_value, 
      pattern = "\\d{8}\\s", 
      replacement = str_sub(
        str_extract(date_value, pattern = "\\d{8}\\s"), 5, 10
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for your time. It looks like I need study up on stringr and REGEX.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract only the 2nd 4-digit year with `sub`.

```
x <- "1/1/20202021 08:07:43 AM"
lubridate::mdy_hms(sub('(\\d{4})(\\d{4})', '\\2', x))
#[1] "2021-01-01 08:07:43 UTC"
```

To apply this to entire column you replace `x` with `df$column_name`.

Comment: This also works! Bonus points for staying in base R, aside from lubridate. Thank you friend. I did not even know that you could pass in sub() as an arg to lubridates family of ymd_hms()

Comment: I do wonder why these regular expressions have escape characters. Isn't the regex for digit `\d` and the back reference supposed to be `\2`? Your code works well though, so obviously I have misunderstood Regular Expressions

Comment: Since a backslash is a special character in R, it needs to be escaped each time it is used with another backslash. There’s a good intro tutorial for regex with R [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-regular-expressions-with-r-df5e897ca432).